# How to do a bulk insert or increment type operation with the Django ORM

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I have a model as defined here:

```
class VectorSet(models.Model):
    word = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    weight = models.IntegerField()
    session = models.ForeignKey(ResearchSession)
```

I want to write a function that will take a list of words and a ResearchSession, and for each word in that list of words if it's doesn't already exist, create a new row with a weight of 1, otherwise take that row and increment weight by 1.

So far I've gotten this:

```
def train(words, session):
    for i in words:
        result, created = VectorSet.objects.get_or_create(word=i, session=session,
                                                          defaults={'weight' : 1})
        if not created:
            result.weight = F('weight') + 1
            result.save()
```

I'm fairly confident that there is a way to do this with one query however I can't quite figure out what that might be or if it's possible to do with django code over raw SQL.

Comment: At least related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2252530/efficent-way-to-bulk-insert-with-get-or-create-in-django-sql-python-django

Comment: Looks perfectly fine to me.

Answer (score 0):

There is currently no out-of-the box solution for doing bulk inserts other than [bulk_create](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#bulk-create) I think. Another solution, depending on your database, is to perform get_or_create within a transaction by using [atomic](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/transactions/#django.db.transaction.atomic). For example:

```
from django.db import transaction

@transaction.atomic
def train(words, session):
    for i in words:
        result, created = VectorSet.objects.get_or_create(word=i, session=session,
                                                      defaults={'weight' : 1})
        if not created:
            result.weight = F('weight') + 1
            result.save()
```

Otherwise, you might be able to use the DB API [executemany](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/#id18):

```
cursor.executemany('INSERT INTO vectorset (field1, field2, field3) VALUES (?, ?, ?)', data)
```

Answer (score 0):

Logic is simple, but we need to hit DB several times, which means several queries:

```
qs = VectorSet.objects.filter(word__in=words, session=session)
qs.update(weiget=models.F('weight')+1)
VectorSet.objects.bulk_insert(VectorSet(session=session, word=w, weight=1)
  for w in words if w not in qs.value_list('word', flat=True))
```

There is also a [`update_or_create`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.update_or_create) in Django 1.7, but currently it does not distinguish defaults for update from defaults for create:

```
for w in words:
    VectorSet.objects.update_or_create(word=w, session=session,
                                    defaults={'weight': models.F('weight')+1})
```

Thus the above code will fail in creating by `int(models.F('weight')+1)` (We could override  the `__int__` method, but too hack to make sense...IMO)