# How to bulk get_or_create in Django?

Tags: python, django, bulkinsert

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2254452/2429989) answer is 10 years old.

Is there a more efficient way for doing the following in 2020 with PostgreSQL?

```
for item in item_list:
    e, new = Entry.objects.get_or_create(
        field1 = item.field1,
        field2 = item.field2,
    )
```

The above approach hits the DB continuously.

Django 2.2 released [`bulk_update`](https://github.com/django/django/pull/9606) and `bulk_create` but a `bulk_get_or_create` doesn't seem to exist?

Comment: If you have the appropriate unique indexes in place you could pass `ignore_conflicts=True` to `bulk_create`?

Comment: I think that's a good approximation for bulk `update_or_create`. I could try and add some queries to get the list first for `get_or_create`. Is there a DB hit when you tigger a unique exception?